# What Ubuntu version to install?

Tags: versions

This is what I have an  Intel® Celeron(R) CPU E3300 @ 2.50GHz × 2

What would be the best version?

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 but it's very slow.

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar

Comment: @Rinzwind probably better to look at the system requirements question instead...

Answer (score 2):

You need a lightweight desktop environment, Unity is quite heavy. To avoid reinstalling the whole system, and save time, you can just install a new desktop environment. I would suggest you to install LXDE with the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install lxde
```

Once it is done, logout and login and choose lxde.

Answer (score 1):

First off it a bad time to be installing Ubuntu with a new LTS release just months away.  As for lightweight Ubuntus go there are many options but I highly recommend the LXDE spins:
 Lubuntu and WattOS

I prefer WattOS, but at this time I would install Lubuntu because the current version of WattOS is EOL.